# How to correct schedule my event weekly with wp_schedule_event()

Tags: php, functions, wp-cron

I want to schedule an event that occurs every friday at 11:30 am and I'm not sure about a few things. I'm current scheduling an event daily at 11:30am from the following code:

```
function my_schedule() {

    $hour = 11;
    $minute = 30;
    $dayofweek = 'today';
    $frequency = 'daily';

    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_event' ) ) {
        $scheduleTime = strtotime($dayofweek." $hour:$minute am America/Montreal");
        wp_schedule_event($scheduleTime, $frequency, 'my_event' );
    } 
}
```

My question is, if I change `$dayofweek` to `friday`, do I need to change `$frequency` to `weekly` since `$scheduleTime` would always be on Fridays? Does `$frequency` make a difference anymore if I have `$scheduleTime` that is set to Friday of each week? How exactly does `$frequency` affect `$scheduleTime` for `wp_schedule_event()`?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) for this function, you can't set up a weekly event by default.

```
wp_schedule_event(int $timestamp, string $recurrence, string $hook, $args = array() );
```

The `$recurrence` value needs to be one of:

- "hourly"
- "twicedaily"
- "daily"

You'll need to test today's date inside your callback function, `my_event`. Something like:

```
function my_event() {
  # date('l') returns the formatted full day of the week 
  if ( date ('l') !== 'Friday' ) {
    return;
  }
  # do my_event things!
}
```

### Edit:

If you want to *add* a weekly cron schedule, you can do it by adding a filter to the [cron_schedules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/cron_schedules/) filter hook. You can see an example of that [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_schedules/), it would work out to something like this:

```
function 246184_weekly_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules[ 'weekly' ] = array( 
        'interval' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, # 604,800, seconds in a week
        'display' => __( 'Weekly' ) );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', '246184_weekly_cron_schedule' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you know how $frequency affects my schedule if $scheduleTime is on a specific date in the future? If $scheduleTime is 1 year in the future and $frequency is daily, does it mean the my event gets called everyday and scheduled 1 year in the future?

Comment: From the docs, it looks like $scheduleTime is the *first time* you need the cron job to run. Frequency is how often it is run after $scheduleTime. The examples on the docs page all use time(), since that's just whatever the first time the page would be loaded up. After that it would be $frequency from $scheduleTime.